# Abstraction before JSF component libraries

Tags: jsf

Is it possible to make an abstraction layer before JSF component libraries (icefaces, primefaces)? How this should be done?

Example: my:DataTable implements ice:DataTable.

I would like to make it easier to switch from one library to another in the future.

Comment: I dont think so! Because there some unique features in every welknown component libraries!

Comment: you can do it by changing the namespace attributes of the page if you use common components of libraries not unique ones. Furthermore, it is impossible to know the behavior.

Comment: @SazzadurRahaman: Good point. Consider making that an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a recent past experience of moving from *Richfaces* to *Primefaces*. I can tell you honestly that, the experience was not a sweet one! You will find in a single [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Richfaces+to+primefaces+conversion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#client=firefox-a&hs=5Rx&hl=en&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=migrate+from+richfaces+to+primefaces+conversion&oq=migrate+from+richfaces+to+primefaces+conversion&gs_l=serp.3...430365.434079.5.434319.13.11.0.0.0.5.2121.5163.3-2j0j1j8-1j1.5.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.8sSWKyoLbZ4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46340616,d.bmk&fp=9bcf567ea9e303f6&biw=1366&bih=596), that how peoples are experiencing difficulties to do the job!

Now to your point, *"making abstraction layer before JSF component libraries"*.

Still this is not possible to do that. The main problem behind that is, component libraries are not the part of the standard or specification. So different popular component library has different excellent distinguished features. [Here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/richfaces/primefaces-vs-richfaces-vs-icefaces) you will find a nice overview of some exclusive features of some of them. If you are more interested you can go through [this thesis](http://is.muni.cz/th/207718/fi_m/thesis.pdf) papers too (that also compares functionality of four popular JavaServer Faces component libraries)!

I think this answers your question!